# AngularJS - Timer directive. Share interval with modal view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

**Hi!** I'm working on a Ionic/Cordova project in which I'm using [Angular Timer](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/)

The timer itself works just fine. This is the code:

```
 <timer ng-click="showLandscape()" interval="1000" countdown="timeType" autostart="false">{{mminutes}}:{{sseconds}}</timer>
```

Now the tricky part is that I need to show the same running timer on landscape mode when the user tap on it (it calls showLandscape() function).

```
ModalService
        .init('templates/modal/cron.html', $scope, 'orientation')
        .then(function(modal) {

        modal.show();

        if (window.plugins && window.plugins.orientationLock)
            window.plugins.orientationLock.lock("landscape");
    });
```

Here I'm calling the modal service to show a template in landscape modal. I'm sharing the `$scope` with it so I can access to it.

I've adapted [this modal example](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/DJgkc). The modal template has other `timer` directive and use the minutes and seconds of the $scope to continue the countdown. But when the modal shows (the user taps on it) the timer on the modal shows the time correctly but it has some kind of delay.

Main window: timer displays 08:49. I tapped on it. Modal display with 08:49 but freezes about 2 seconds and then show 08:48. If I close the modal (by tapping the timer again -thus calling closeModal()-) the main window's timer is correct and continue working (because it was always working on background).

I've tried different approaches to this issue:

- Create other controller. It was not useful since I need to share a lot of more info besides the timer and I was duplicating a lot of code.
- Search a way to change the layout of the same controller whenever its portrait or landscape mode. Didn't find any. I can set the orientation (via plugin) but the template is always the same.
- Modal works fine. It shows all the other stuff and works ok. Unfortunately if it does not display the time correctly it makes the modal useless.

Target: Android/iOS on a Ionic/Cordova Project.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show an example of the timer working / hanging in your codepen please?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Couldn't add timer to the codepen. I get a bunch of js errors.

Comment: You should be able to include the JS files to have the timer working.

Comment: Why not abandon Angular timing and just create your own? $timeout(function() {$scope.nowtime = sometimeyouprovide}, 1000) isn't that complicated.

Comment: @Rienk yeah I'm thinking in using other ways. This timer directive is giving me more problems than solutions and I'm running out of time ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Patch it

After inspecting the code of this directive, The best for your case is to get the timer values out of the `<timer>` directive, as for now this is **not supported by the maintainer** of this project.

However, this is **definitely possible** and iv'e **[forked](https://github.com/jossef/angular-timer/blob/master/dist/angular-timer.js)** the original repository to patch the `<timer>` directive to support it.

#### The Result - http://codepen.io/Jossef/pen/OypOQg?editors=101

---

**So what's changed?**; the original directive's scope is isolated. meaning that `hours`, `minutes`, ... , variables are not exported for external use. the addition is minor, e.g.

[image]

The only workaround after patching this, had to listen to the `<timer>` tick event and to `digest` the scope so that the bounded values will reflect their values without a delay.

```
$scope.$on('timer-tick', function(event, args) {
  $timeout(angular.noop);
});
```

### Usage

To use the patched directive, replace and include this in your HTML

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jossef/angular-timer/master/dist/angular-timer.js"></script>
```

---

## Online Demo - http://codepen.io/Jossef/pen/OypOQg?editors=101

Comment: Wow. That's just awesome! I'm accepting this. Thanks Jossef!

Comment: Great!, FYI this change [merged into the original repository](https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer/pull/219), so keep updated with the upcoming release! https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer/pull/219

Comment: Ok! I'm new to all this angularJS stuff. My deadline is this Tuesday and I was going nuts. The delay made the application useless and the customer wasn't happy lol. So Thanks again. Lesson learned.